# How to import two exports with the same name from the same file

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript file that looks like this:

```
export interface Prisma {
    // Members
}

export const Prisma = (): Prisma => {
    // returns a object with of type Prisma
};
```

Given that both of these entities have the same name in the same file (which I can't change), how can I import the interface in another file? Writing

```
import Prisma from './myFile';
```

always imports the exported `const`, never the exported `interface`.

Comment: Might you export your const as a default like `export default = (): Prisma => {};` and then you'll be able to import it like `import Prisma from ./myFile;` while an interface should then be imported like `import {Prisma} from ./myFile;`
`

Comment: I can't change the file the importing from unfortunately

Comment: I gave it a try and what I can see is that just by importing `Prisma` from your file typescript automatically distinguished whether your `Prisma` is referring to a `const` or to an `interface`. That makes sense since for example a return type of a function cannot be a `const`, but rather an `interface`.

Comment: Ah, I see, TS works out which export you need based on context! Thanks a lot, can't think why I didn't just try `class MyClass implements Prisma`. If you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically typescript will infer your `Prisma` based on where you use it, for example:

```
// Prisma.ts
export interface Prisma {
  value: string;
}

export const Prisma = (): Prisma => {
  return { value: "Some value" };
};

// File.ts
import { Prisma } from '.Prisma';

class MyClass implements Prisma {
  value: string = "Initial value"; // => implement *interface*
  // ...

  getPrismaValue() {
    return Prisma().value; // => execute Prisma *function*, yields "Some value"
  }
}
```